# Marshal C# and Emscripten - Callback

Tags: javascript, c#, interop, marshalling, emscripten

I am trying to create a **C# method** and link it to an existing **JavaScript method** but I have some difficulties with [Marshal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/) usage.
I tried to include my questions in the code as it will be easier to understand.

Here is the javascript method

```
// What are the types of those parameters ?
JS_WebRequest_SetHandler: function (request, arg, onresponse)
{
    var http = wr.requestInstances[request];
    http.onload = function http_onload(e) {
    // ...
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(http.response);
    var buffer = _malloc(byteArray.length);
    HEAPU8.set(byteArray, buffer);
    Runtime.dynCall('viiii', onresponse, [arg, http.status, buffer, byteArray.length]);
    // ...
}
```

Here is the C# content

```
// Are the types right ?
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void JS_WebRequest_SetHandler(int request, IntPtr arg, IntPtr onresponse);

public void SetHandler(string arg) // Example with a string
{
    // How can I link the OnResponse method to the JS_WebRequest_SetHandler onresponse ?
    // What types should I use ?
    JS_WebRequest_SetHandler(request, arg, onresponse);
}

// Are those types right ?
public void OnResponse(IntPtr arg, IntPtr status, IntPtr buffer, IntPtr length)
{
    // How can I extract the data of each argument ?
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did I get it right that you're doing that for Unity WebGL target? Have you found a solution?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Yep this was linked with the Unity WebGL and the way they handle http requests. But according to the new version of Unity 5.2 this might not longer be a problem because of the new way they handle it.

Comment: Where is it written exactly? The page on JS plugins doesn't mention `Runtime.dynCall` at all. By the way, this was the part that my code was lacking. Thank you.